# Breeze how to write write a single Breeze Entity Query that will return results that span across multiple entities that relate

Tags: entity, breeze

I would like to write a single Breeze Entity Query that will return results that span across multiple entities that relate.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

The following returns Stages from Institution

```
var queryStages = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("institution")
    .where("stages", "any", "qualifiedName", "==", 'QA');
```

and

The following returned Stage Config from Stages

```
var queryStageConfigs = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("stages")
    .where("stageConfig", "any", "configValue", "==", 'Green');
```

How can I write a single Breeze Entity Query to do this all in one call.
I really want to be able write queries that go as deep as I want to go through my entities.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you looked at the `expand()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this using a [composite where clause](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#CompositeWhere).  This deep drill into related entities is similar to the last example in the "conditions on related properties" section [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#WhereRelated).

```
var predicate = breeze.Predicate
    .create("stages", "any", "qualifiedName", "==", 'QA')
    .or("stages", "any", "stageConfig", "any", "configValue", "==", "Green");

var query = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("institution")
    .where(predicate);
```